# Is "going to get you" means "going to give you"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it correct to say "this place must gonna get you some nice shots (pictures)? 
And What is "it's not going to get you any far" means?

Comment: Do you have online sources for these statements? If so, can you give a link?

Comment: I don't have link.

Comment: Can you tell us where you heard these sentences? Who said them (not their name) and where you/they were at the time? Or if they're sentences you made up yourself, let us know that.

Comment: Those phrases can certainly overlap… and they can also mean very differrent things.

Either way, you'll prolly get more help somewhere such as English Language Learners…

Comment: I saw this sentence "it's not going to get you any far" in tumblr, someone posted that with a huge caption, so I took that sentence from there and I made the other one by myself.

Answer (score 1):

"Must gonna" is not grammatical in any standard variety of English that I've ever met, though I'm quite ready to believe that there are dialects where people say it.

In that context I would interpret "get you" as "let you get". It's not a standard way of expressing it.

"It's not going to get you any far" is also not any variety of English that I recognise. I would assume that it is a mistake for "it's not going to get you **very** far", which is idiomatic, and means "It won't help you much".

Comment: "This place must gonna let you get some nice shots" Is it correct now?

Comment: @Lucia: To repeat (and endorse) Colin's first words above, *"Must gonna" is **not grammatical** in any standard variety of English,* so no.

Comment: Can you help me to correct this sentence? What can I use instead of "must gonna"?

Comment: _Must gonna_ is a non-standard way of rendering _must_ in the future tense. So unless you're writing a rap song, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following grammatical changes:

> This place will most likely provide you with some nice pictures.

to **go far**, [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-far) the antonym of 'it's not going to get you very far'.

> to be successful in what you try to do
>
> With all her skill and ambition, I’m sure Leah will go far.
>
> To be, or to become successful:punch above your weight, thrive,
>   prosper

Comment: The phrase used was _get you far_, which is different from _go far_.

Comment: "This place will most likely provide you with some nice pictures" this sentence seems so formal.